# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, firebase, classnotfoundexception, logfactory

I am trying to send a notification using this class [FCMHelper](https://github.com/MOSDEV82/fcmhelper/blob/master/FCMHelper.java) and im getting errors 
errors leading me to an error in httpclient 
this is my code ...

```
public void send() throws IOException{
    JsonObject notificationObject = new JsonObject();
    notificationObject.addProperty("data", "hello");
    notificationObject.addProperty("to", "dSvX_cWo5iY:A......QQT-bkb8x0VO");
    FireBase firebase = FireBase.getInstance();
    firebase.sendNotification("to", "condition", notificationObject);
}
```

i got this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    ... 58 more
```

what the problem here or if someone could give any other way to do it

.. thanks for your help

Comment: Did you Try posting The Exception in Google

Comment: i tried but never got a solution

Comment: i posted the error in google and found lots of hints that point to what is in the answer below

Comment: i tried the solution below but nothing changed ...  Kukeltje

Comment: I doubt that if you added Apache commons logging **correctly** this error still happens

Comment: as mentioned before .. when i added Apache commons logging to my project .. the server error stack is gone .. but that didn't solve my real problem

Comment: The title of this question is kind of to broad. The class not found exception is gone so this real problem is solved and this question is a duplicate of ,any others. Close it, remove it or    whatever amd create a new question about the next problem and describe and analyze it carefully.

Comment: And above you said you tried ot and nothing changed... contradictory comments

Comment: I 'corrected' the title and tags for you, so you have an impression what a better title is and the tags to. I removed the android tag since this real  CNFE occures server side and is not related to using android (it would fail from a desktop to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems  "org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory" is missed.
Have you imported the library?

Comment: im not using LogFactory in my bean neither the class FCMHelper do .. why should i import it ??

Comment: The log says ClassNotFoundException...so you should try IMO

Comment: i tried it and got nothing .. but the server error stack didn't appear

Comment: im still fresh student in JSF and android and mr @ FrancescoAzzola gave a reasonable solution .. but it didn't work in my case

Comment: i receive notification from firebase console but i couldn't send json from jsf to firebase ..